# How to change the yaxis labels on plot model using sjplots package in R

Tags: r, sjplot

I applied linear regression(lm) model for my dataset. I got the expected results(as values) but the output holds the label name in all categories.
Dataset seems: (Just a sample data for reference)

```
DARM        Val hba_diff
Category1   23  2.5 
Category2   54  3.8
Category3   56  5.2
Category4   89  6.1
```

Results after applying the below lm model :

lm(formula = hba_diff ~ DARM, data = DARM_data)

Output

```
Predictors       Estimates  CI          p
(Intercept)      0.00      -0.10 – 0.10 0.957
DARM [Category1] 0.23      -0.30 – 0.75 0.398
DARM [Category2] 0.06      -0.25 – 0.37 0.719
DARM [Category3] 1.00      -2.18 – 4.17 0.538
DARM [Category4] -0.84     -2.67 – 1.00 0.372
```

I need to remove the 'DARM' in all rows of the output.
Kindly suggest a code to remove the 'DARM' term in output set.

Expected output:

```
Predictors       Estimates  CI          p
(Intercept)      0.00      -0.10 – 0.10 0.957
Category1        0.23      -0.30 – 0.75 0.398
Category2        0.06      -0.25 – 0.37 0.719
Category3        1.00      -2.18 – 4.17 0.538
Category4        -0.84     -2.67 – 1.00 0.372
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include the full code in the future. Not sure how you get the table, I guess you are using `tab_model` function in `sjplot`, so the easiest way is to provide the names, for example:

```
library(sjPlot)

df = data.frame(hba_diff=runif(50),
DARM = sample(c("Category1","Category2","Category3"),50,replace=TRUE))

fit = lm(hba_diff ~ DARM, data = df)

tab_model(fit,pred.labels = c("Intercept","Category2","Category3"))
```

[image]

To plot, do something likewise with ggplot2 (the plot is coord flipped so it is x axis):

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_model(fit) + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Category2","Category3"))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I have them for tab_model. But I want them to use in plot model how to remove the  "DARM [Category1]" and have  "Category1". kindly help me

Comment: can you edit your question accordingly and place the full code

Comment: Is that works with sort.est =TRUE as like order ????